# Rotating passwords in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, passwords, mysql-workbench

We are rotating our database passwords regularly and I want to automatically update the password on our developers machines.

The process should ideally look like this:
Every morning a script should run which does the following

1. Get the new password for the database from our secrets manager
2. Update the password used by MySQL Workbench when connecting to this database.

Is there any way I can automatically update the password in MySQL Workbench via a script? I am wanting to avoid having the developers manually rotate the password every day.

Comment: You can update the passwords with a simple sql script. What is your secrets manager? The biggest problem is probably getting the new passwords from there.

Comment: Getting the password is not a problem. How do I update the MySQL Workbench saved connection profile with the new password?